# How to display the contents of a map when we know the key

Tags: html, angular, dictionary

I'm trying to display the contents of a map using the key. My key is a string like:

```
processus.id/critere.id/detail.actif.id !!
```

For example... when I do this:

```
map['1/2/3'].valeur.id
```

I'll get the `valeur.id` for the key '1/2/3'. Here 1 = processus.id and 2 = critere.id and 3 = detail.actif.id !!! but I can't give the key manually, it want to create a loop and recover keys.

Here's my code (it's a part of my table):

```
<tr *ngFor="let detail of classifTab?.details">
   <td>{{detail.actif.nom}}</td>
   <ng-container *ngFor="let processus of classifTab?.lesProcessus">
      <td *ngFor="let critere of processus?.critereProcessuses">{{detail.mapClassif["'"+processus.id+"/"+critere.id+"/"+detail.actif.id+"'"]?.valeur.id}}</td>
   </ng-container>
</tr>
```

it does not give me anything. Maybe the problem is the key because when i give the string manually like map['1/2/3'].valeur.id, it give me the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `{{detail.mapClassif["'"+processus.id+"/"+critere.id+"/"+detail.actif.id+"'"]?.valeur.id}}`

with

```
{{detail.mapClassif[processus.id+"/"+critere.id+"/"+detail.actif.id]?.valeur.id}}
```

quotes are not required.

I have created a simple stackblitz example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wurn9a